# How to print result from alamofire response using codable

Tags: ios, alamofire, codable, swift5

New to codable and i have tried to create a class for alamofire with codable and tried to make an api request. I have getting some Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch  error and i figured it out it because of my model class. Now what i need is i want to print alamofire response in JSON(String) formate before it decoding so that i can identify the typeMismatch

```
static func performRequest<T:Decodable>(route:APIRouter, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion:@escaping (Result<T,Error>)->Void) -> DataRequest {

    return AF.request(route)
        .responseDecodable (decoder: decoder){ (response: DataResponse<T>) in
            print(response.result)
            completion(response.result)
    }
}
```

i want some code to print the actual result from alamofire

Comment: It's rather impossible to answer the question without the JSON and the model.

Comment: @vadian i need only one method for printing the alamofire result in string format. Why because need to compare the model class and JSON response  for fixing the TypeMismatch error

Comment: Get the data with a standard request and print the string representation of the `Data`. In my opinion huge libraries like Alamofire are overkill anyway to decode JSON from a simple GET request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can print the raw `Data` in your `responseDecodable` closure by grabbing it from the `DataResponse`:

```
print(response.data.map { String(decoding: $0, as: UTF8.self) } ?? "No data.")
```

You can also add a separate serializer just to see the `String`:

```
.responseDecodable { }
.responseString { }
```

If you just want to see the response for debugging, you can `debugPrint` the response in the closure. This will print the request and response body datas as `String`s.

```swift
.responseDecodable(of: T.self) { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Comment: How do i check network status inside .responseDecodable { } ?

Comment: You can access any error, including network errors, from the response's error property.